# Passing csv-file productlinks to scrapy start_url

Tags: python, excel, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

**Intro**
My crawler did good work and scraped every productlink i wanted and created .csv file, where all productslinks are stored in column A, round about i got ~5k links.

**Task**
Passing the productlinks to my spiders start_urls grab the data i want

My aim is to have a csv file, with all attributes from only "english-urls", another csv, with all attributes of only "german-urls"

I've read a question on stackoverflow:
([Scrapy - Importing Excel .csv as start_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516997/scrapy-importing-excel-csv-as-start-url),
but none of these solutions helped me.

**ErrorMSG**
My .py file and my csv file i want to read informations from, are both stored in the same directory.

[image]

**My current code**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import OutofcsvItem



class DuifSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "duif"
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []

    f = open('duiffinal.csv', 'r')
    for i in f:
        u = i.split('\n')
        start_urls.append(u[0])


    def parse_items(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//div[@class="heading"]')

        if not card:
            print('No productlink', response.url)

        for a in card:
            items = OutofcsvItem()
            items['Link'] = response.url
            items['SKU'] = response.xpath('.//p[@class="desc"]/text()').get().strip()
            items['Title'] = response.xpath('.//h1[@class="product-title"]/text()').get()
            yield items
```

Comment: https://github.com/ejulio/spider-feeder

Comment: @Gallaecio thanks for you recommendation,in my console i can see, that my spiders crawls the links out of my csv/txt, but it does not scrape my attributes on the final productpages, can you help me with that?

Comment: i added in my settings.py : ```EXTENSIONS = {
    'spider_feeder.loaders.StartUrlsAndMetaLoader': 0
}

SPIDERFEEDER_INPUT_URI = './duifonlylinks.csv'```